# Getting all <input> inside the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I display in my console the list of all `<input>` tags inside the HTML?

I've tried to use `$('input')`, `$(':input')`, or even `$('tbody input')` all of those commands returns `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[<number>]`.

Anyways, I am using Google Chrome. Yet I think it wouldn't affect other browsers, which of course IE is an exemption.

Comment: You need to call it once DOM is ready

Comment: Use `$('input').get()` to get it as a list of DOMElements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input')` is the correct approach. `$(...)` returns a *jQuery object* and `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[<number>]` is the console's representation of such an object.

It means that you have an *array like object*, constructed by the function `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init`, with `<number>` elements.

That's **normal**, your code works fine (at least in this regard), `$('input')` is the correct approach.

---

Of course you should make to select the elements after the document is loaded, which is all explained the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: Doesn't it mean jQuery empty object?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Could be, if `<number>` is `0`.

Comment: Even an empty object returns jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]. I don't know what this number means btw

Comment: Interesting. Anyways, I understood the question such that the OP is confused about the output in general, but there is nothing wrong with it. *edit:* If you do `console.dir([1,2,3])` you see a similar output. The number usually represents the number of elements in the array. However, things might work differently for array-like objects. I wouldn't interpret too much into console output in this regard anyway.

Comment: FWIW, an empty jQuery shows `0` for me: `console.dir($())` shows `e.fn.e.init[0]`, but `console.dir($(document.body))` shows `e.fn.e.init[1]`.

Comment: It's good to hear that my code is correct. Yet as I try to access the elements from it using a for loop, it only iterates once. How can I access all the elements using `$("input[name='someName']")` where the console output of it is `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[size]`?

Comment: @Dr.Java `$("input[name='someName']").each(function() { console.log(this); });` should work just fine. If it doesn't, then there is probably something else wrong, and you would have to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't get other JQuery functions to work on the every element in the array. Like the `parent` and `find` method on the `this`?

Comment: @Dr.Java: `this` is a DOM element. If you want to create a jQuery object from `this`, pass it to jQuery: `$(this)`. Have a look at the examples in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/each/.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the code in documnet ready to ensure that dom is loaded.also you dont even need jquery for that:

```
var allinput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a call inside your DOMReady event as follows:

```
$(function() {  
    var inputs = $('input');
    console.log(inputs);
});
```